# Deep watch changes in form only after data is loaded not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My goal is having an update button which is disabled unless the data in the form has been changed. For this I'm deep watching the form data. The problem is that the form changes once on page load when I call the api for the user data. So logically I thought I could just use `this.loading` to conditionally set `this.changed` to true. For some reason it doesn't work.

Looking at my code, I feel like `this.changed` variable shouldn't be set to true, because `this.loading` isn't false yet, but it sets `this.changed` to true anyways. (Because `this.loading` somehow is already false when the form changes, but looking at the `then` part of the `fetchUser` function it
should only change before `this.loading` is set to false, so It should be ignored. Im confused.)

```
    watch: {
        form: {
            handler: function() {
                if (!this.loading) {
                    this.changed = true;
                }
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchUser();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchUser(id) {
            this.loading = true;
            UserApiService.fetchUser(id !== undefined ? id : this.$route.params.id, (r) => {
                this.form = r.data;
                this.loading = false;
            });
        }
    }

// User api service
function fetchUser(id, then) {
    axios.get(url + id).then(r => then(r));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Vue is using [async update queue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) to do the rendering/updates and calling watchers...

What happens is that when the `this.form = r.data;` line is executed, your watcher is not executed immediately (in the middle of your code) - Vue just registers the change and runs the watcher later (asynchronously)...when `loading` is already set to `false`

To work around this you can use `nextTick()` function to postpone the `loading` property update to "next render cycle":

```js
  this.form = r.data;
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.loading = false;
  })
```

Comment: I tried using `setTimeout` thinking about the update queue this didnt work though. I never used `nextTick` before, it worked!